# Creating action event for the component inside Object of another class(treated as component) into the class where object is created in javaFx?

Tags: java, object, javafx, javafx-2, actionevent

CustomItem Class:

```
public class MenuItem {
private GridPane menuItem;
private Label itemCode,itemPrice;
private TextArea itemName;

public MenuItem(){
    itemCode=new Label();
    itemName=new TextArea();
    itemPrice=new Label();
}

public GridPane getMenuItemBox(){
    menuItem=new GridPane();

    menuItem.add(itemCode, 0, 0);
    menuItem.add(itemName, 0, 1);
    menuItem.add(itemPrice, 0, 2);


    return menuItem;
}
```

Controller Class: (where the object of above class will get created and added)

```
public class ItemController implements Initializable{
@FXML
private FlowPane mainCategory,itemSection;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        MenuItem mi=new MenuItem();
        itemSection.getChildren().add(mi.getMenuItemBox());

    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to add

```
setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("click successful !");
    }
});
```

action for the Labels defined in  `MenuItem` class. How could I do that in `ItemController` class ?
I want `action events` should be in `ItemController` as we create for already defined components like`(button,label,etc.)`
which could be similar to `mi.getItemCodeLabel.setOnMouseClicked.`

How I could achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you access them? They are private. Do you have getter methods that you don't include here?

Comment: @JamesWierzba No, I don't have. The getters and setters will be used for the action to be performed wherever it is used & related to the class where object is been created only.
But here, `onAction` of specific label I want to modify that component(object)

Answer (score 0):

Just define methods in your `MenuItem` class to register handlers. e.g.

```
public class MenuItem {

    private GridPane menuItem;
    private Label itemCode,itemPrice;
    private TextArea itemName;

    public MenuItem(){
        itemCode=new Label();
        itemName=new TextArea();
        itemPrice=new Label();
    }

    public GridPane getMenuItemBox(){
        menuItem=new GridPane();

        menuItem.add(itemCode, 0, 0);
        menuItem.add(itemName, 0, 1);
        menuItem.add(itemPrice, 0, 2);


        return menuItem;
    }

    public <E extends Event> void addCodeHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
        itemCode.addEventHandler(eventType, handler);
    }

    public <E extends Event> void addPriceHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
        itemPrice.addEventHandler(eventType, handler);
    }

    public <E extends Event> void removeCodeHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
        itemCode.removeEventHandler(eventType, handler);
    }

    public <E extends Event> void removePriceHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
        itemPrice.removeEventHandler(eventType, handler);
    }

}
```

and then you can do

```
menuItem.addCodeHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> 
    System.out.println("Click successful!"));
```

etc.

This approach avoids exposing the labels from your class, either as fields or via methods.

Here is a complete example, which you can run:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomComponentWithEventHandling extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane itemSelection = new FlowPane();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++)  {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            String itemCode = "Item "+i;
            item.setItemCode(itemCode);
            item.setItemPrice(100);

            item.addCodeHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
                System.out.println("Clicked on label for "+itemCode);
            });

            item.addPriceHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
                System.out.println("Clicked on price for "+itemCode);
            });

            itemSelection.getChildren().add(item.getMenuItemBox());
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(itemSelection), 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class MenuItem {

        private GridPane menuItem;
        private Label itemCode,itemPrice;
        private TextArea itemName;

        public MenuItem(){
            itemCode=new Label();
            itemName=new TextArea();
            itemPrice=new Label();
        }

        public GridPane getMenuItemBox(){
            menuItem=new GridPane();

            menuItem.add(itemCode, 0, 0);
            menuItem.add(itemName, 0, 1);
            menuItem.add(itemPrice, 0, 2);


            return menuItem;
        }

        public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
            this.itemCode.setText(itemCode);
        }

        public void setItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
            this.itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(itemPrice));
        }

        public <E extends Event> void addCodeHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
            itemCode.addEventHandler(eventType, handler);
        }

        public <E extends Event> void addPriceHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
            itemPrice.addEventHandler(eventType, handler);
        }

        public <E extends Event> void removeCodeHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
            itemCode.removeEventHandler(eventType, handler);
        }

        public <E extends Event> void removePriceHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> handler) {
            itemPrice.removeEventHandler(eventType, handler);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work for events to be triggered in the calling class. But I think this will not be useful for triggering events in that Object(component)
What will be the use case of removePriceHandler?

Comment: what enentType & hadler will contain in (enentType,handler) could you give me exmaple?

Comment: And I do not understand your first comment. I thought you wanted to be able to register event handlers with the labels defined in your `MenuItem` class from outside, which is what this code lets you do. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. @James_D